# complex mysql query to list record date wise

Tags: php, mysql

i have a user table with user registered and it has date of registration of user now i am trying to write a query to list the user date wise ie there will be a date and below it all the users registered on that date and there will be next date and below it all users registered on that date .......

the same way they are listing these videos http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/

i am trying to write a mysql query for the above

```
CREATE TABLE `member` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(2500) NOT NULL,
  `locality` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `dttm` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `memtype` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active',
  `open_identity` varchar(2500) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=137 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=137 ;
```

Comment: Take a look at the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function of mysql.

Comment: Have you tried for some query? If yes then please add in post.

Comment: I Think you are trying to list all the users depends on created_at field.. Am I right?

Comment: yes right trying to list all users with there date crated as heading as videos shown in the link

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: why are n't using ORDER BY command ?

Comment: just by using order by i wont be able to list users date wise ie all users registered on same date will be listed with heading of that date

Comment: Can you explain your problem with example? Because I could n't get you..

Comment: @AjithaMs pls chek the video listed with date heading here http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/

Comment: I have slightly confused with your sample video. In this video, right side bar is expected result right?. All those are recently updated videos list right..